# Are there any HTML coding conventions/style/standard

Tags: html, coding-style

I mean to name ids, names, values, etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I don't think there is a single, accepted naming conventions for naming HTML elements, you might find the following article helpful. The content starting on page two is probably most helpful. Good luck!

**[The Meaning of Semantics Take II: Naming Conventions for Class and ID in CSS](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170514)**

Here are a few good paragraphs that summarize what the author is trying to get at:

> A designer might name a column
>   division #leftnav. At first glance
>   this is logical, and in the context of
>   smaller sites, maintained by one or
>   just a few folks, there really aren't
>   a lot of problems with this kind of
>   naming.
>
> However, consider a site the size of
>   AOL or Yahoo, on which large teams of
>   designers and developers manage
>   millions of pages every day. And let's
>   say that a design decision from high
>   on up the corporate ladder is made to
>   move the navigation to the right from
>   its former home on the left side of
>   the screen. Part of the power of CSS
>   is that in a best-case scenario, all
>   that switching the navigation would
>   require is to go into the CSS and swap
>   the column by repositioning it or
>   floating it right instead of left.
>   Save that file and then millions of
>   documents are updated to reflect the
>   change.
>
> But now, millions of documents also
>   have a division with an ID of #leftnav
>   describing a column that appears on
>   the right! Without doing a massive
>   search and replace to change the ID
>   name in the (X)HTML, the document is
>   now very confusing to anyone who views
>   source, or (more importantly) comes in
>   to work on the site.
>
> This is why avoiding presentation and
>   choosing a more relevant description
>   as simple as #nav or #subnav will be
>   more useful in that kind of
>   environment. So, even if it might seem
>   a bit nitpicky, for very large sites
>   we want to try and maintain the power
>   of CSS and the purity of our
>   documents. Smart class and ID names
>   are a major part of that goal.

Comment: +1 for the mere mention of semantics wrt naming

Comment: +1 for copying and pasting the interesting bit. Laziness ftw.

Comment: I always try to copy and paste the interesting stuff for two reasons. The first is laziness. The second is that links break over time, and I like to think of Stack Overflow as a repository that stuff should be dumped into, not just linked from.

Answer (score 4):

[w3c](http://w3c.org/) recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

With anyone interested in standards I always recommend these two books:

Designing with Web Standards (2nd Edition) (Paperback)

[Eric Meyer on CSS: Mastering the Language of Web Design (VOICES) (Paperback)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073571245X)

Those two books were instrumental in helping me cultivate my own standards.

Answer (score 0):

If there was one, the world would be a better place, the unicorns wouldn't be extinct, and so on. It's like deciding on indentation or brace style.

Just try to keep it consistent and sane. By sane I don't mean 'indent with 4 spaces and name with camelCase', just that you follow a style consistently. underscore_names? more power to you. tabs to the rescue? great. I'd just like not to open new projects and have to cuss for 5 minutes because the indentation is completely hosed, and stuff inside a div is three tabs to the left of it.

Fortunately, a good editor helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has one [here](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/html/), which is what I would follow.